# body terminal of PMOS in transmission gate

Tags: mosfet, switches, integrated-circuit

Why is the body terminal of PMOS in the transmission gate connected to VDD instead of its source? Why do we deliberately introduce body effect here?

Comment: Well...if it's connected to the source like most diodes then there it produces a diode antiparallel to the source-drain causing it to be unable to block current in both directions making it unsuitable for a transmission gate.

Comment: What do you mean by diode here?

Comment: Exactly what I said. It produces a diode. You have to look at the physical structure of MOSFET and the way the P and N-doped silicone connects together to see why. That little diode symbol inside a typical MOSFET symbol isn't there for no reason.

Comment: And if you connect the PMOS body to anything other than the most positive voltage in the system, or the NMOS body to anything other than the most negative voltage in the system, the it cannot block all voltages in the system.

Comment: Does this mean that the latch up effect can also be eliminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why do we deliberately introduce body effect here?*

We're not deliberately introducing the body diode - we're deliberately trying to connect it to a voltage so that the body diode is as much reverse biased as we can get it to be. This then allows the PMOSFET to block current when it has the drain voltage higher than its source voltage.

If we didn't do this the PMOSFET body diode would become forward biased as soon as the source voltage was lower than the drain voltage and, it would be a very good transmission gate / analogue switch. Look at the symbol for a standard 3 pin PMOSFET on the right: -

[image]

Can you see the parasitic body diode represented in the diagram? Can you see that if the drain voltage exceeds the source voltage by a few hundred millivolts, drain current would flow through the body diode and this particular configuration would be ineffective as a blocking device.